# How to deploy an upstream .war as an OpenShift app's ROOT.war?

Tags: maven, liferay, jboss7.x, openshift

**Background of issue:**

I've begun using OpenShift for the goal of -- ostensibly -- installing and managing a Liferay 6.2 portal via OpenShift. For this goal, I've created an OpenShift application using the jbossas-7 and postgresql-9.2 cartridges -- my so far preferring the official cartridges, as such, compared to the "DIY cartridge" approach, namely with regards to installing an application server on OpenShift, specifically JBoss AS7,and ideally of installing Liferay within that application server.

Following along with the instructions in the Liferay User Guide[1], albeit in endeavoring to adjust those instructions for a deployment onto JBoss AS7 in OpenShift, I've configured my OpenShift apps' modules directory and downloaded the upstream liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1-20131101192857659.war then updating the .war file with the removal of eclipselink.jar (as specified[1]) furthermore with addition of a custon portal-ext.properties. I've located the modified .war file at ${APP}/deployments/ROOT.war

In the Maven configuration for the JBoss part of the app, I've commented out the maven-war-plugin entry in pom.xml, my hoping that the deployments/ROOT.war file would then be used as the app's ROOT.war file in the JBoss server in the app's OpenShift Online space. The issue, so far as I understand, is that that doesn't seem to be happening as expected -- that, instead, even with the specified Maven plugin configuration commented-out, it seems that the app's own code is beig used in creating a new ROOT.war overriding the existing deployments/ROOT.war.

Frankly that is only guess as far as what's the case. Separately there's some difficulty that happens in the 'git push' - in short, the Maven build during the 'git push' fails, during the server-restart part. I can [re]start the app via the OpenShift Online console, then, but what I see then at http://portal-gproj.rhcloud.com/ it's not the Liferay ROOT.war, rather it a .war file containing the static content I made in adapting OpenShift's own default index.html, shortly after assembling the app via 'rhc'

When I SSH to my app's remote host on OpenShift Online, I see that same ROOT.war as I've modified for using Liferay is located at app-root/repo/deployments/ROOT.war. However, it's apparently not being installed from the app's 'deployments' dir as the app's own ROOT.war, under the live JBoss instance.

**Assuming that that may be due to a (combined app/openshift) Maven configuration being used during the 'git push' part of the workflow (???) my question is this:** Is there a way to work around that behavior of the toolchain, so as to ensure that my own provided ROOT.war will be used as the app's ROOT.war?

(Separately, is there a way to configure JBoss AS7 for more verbose log output? The info from the logs for the JBoss AS 7 cartridge as installed by the OpenShift tools, it seems to have been of only limited use as far debugging this app's configuration. This app is now in its second iteration, incidentally -- was deleted once and will be deleted and re-created in a third time, shortly)

[1] http://liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/installing-liferay-on-jboss-7-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-15-en

**UPDATE** Buried in the output from the most recent 'git push' step in the workflow, there's a message, "Disk quota exceeded". I'm assuming that's due to the size of the Liferay WAR file, all couple-hundred megs of it. It's confusing, to say the least:

```
remote: HAProxy instance is started
remote: Deploying JBoss
remote: rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
remote: rsync: write failed on "/var/lib/openshift/52a2f112e0b8cd711a000007/jbossas/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war": Disk quota exceeded (122)
remote: rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(301) [receiver=3.0.6]
remote: rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (28 bytes received so far) [sender]
remote: rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
remote: Result: failure
```

I'm assuming that's due to the space occupied by the Git repository for the app -- the app's Git repository, on this approach, would contain all of the original Liferay Portal .war file, the expanded contents of the file, and the modified .war file as intended to be used in this app. Presently, I'll try to refactor my approach to creating the third one of those -- instead of the "Expand, modify, and recompress" approach rather to try to use a Maven JAR file "overlay" as I've read of, so that ideally only one copy of the large upstream .war file should ever be needed in the repository (alternately, maybe pulling in a plain GitHub repository via a Git 'external', to pass off the repository storage to GitHub rather than my app's limited storage space?).

I'm afraid that the "JAR file overlay" approach will result in a lot of latency in the App's "git push" part, whereas the Liferay .war is a large JAR file to have to modify. However, if it works for the goal of at least creating a Liferay portal on OpenShift, that would be the goal.....

If there  may be any advice available as far as the matter, "Upstream .war as ROOT.war" -- if, pending a resolution of the disk quota issue, in regards to the overall workflow in "That part" of the project -- if the "Comment out the maven-war-plugin" thing may not be sufficient for using an upstream .war as ROOT.war, I would appreciate any advice as to this configuration.

Comment: Found an item in the KB[1]. It would be relevant in this configuration.

Is there any word as to whether Liferay may ever be provided via an official OpenShift cartridge?

[1] https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear

Comment: Deleting the app, going to try it again with a different SCCM approach - will use the OpenShift app's Git repository as a submodule to a module from which I can manage the changesets with regards to the upstream .war file, the latter of which may be managed with a repository at GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Referring to *[OpenShift KB-E1088](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear)*, I'll use the SCP approach -- this onto JBoss AS7. To define some additional mechanism in order to manage the project's upstream sources with, as so:

**Component Naming Schema**

app.manager.name = `${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}-${OPENSHIFT_NAMESPACE}-manage`

- Use ${app.manager.name} as the name of a Git respository hosted at GitHub
- Use ${app.manager.name} also as the Maven Artifact ID in the root POM within that repository's source tree

app.manager.group = `${OPENSHIFT_NAMESPACE).openshift.${USER_APP_DOMAIN_NAME}`

- Use ${app.manager.group} as the Maven Artifact Group ID for the same item

**Tasks for ${app.manager.group}:${app.manager.name}**

- set `openshift.origin.domain = "rhcloud.com"`
- Add the following Git repository as a submodule to the -manage repository, named `app` : `ssh://${OPENSHIFT_APP_UID}@{OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}-${OPENSHIFT_NAMESPACE}.${openshift.origin.domain}`
- Also add the item as a Maven module of the -manage artifact's POM
- Download the upsream Liferay `.war` file
- Apply a JAR file *overlay* onto the local `.war` file

  - Add custom `portal-ext.properties`
  - remove `eclipselink.jar`
- Upload the modified `.war` file

**Additional Tasks Required**

- *Presumably in the Git repository for the OpenShift app itself*

  - **Modify the `jbossas` cartridge `modules` configuration** such that the resulting modules configuration will be suitable to the Liferay installation represented in the upstream `.war` file

    - Add such JAR files as needed for the Liferay portal and for the portal's JDBC configuration
    - Using local copies of upstream `module.xml` files in the app's `jbossas` cartridge on OpenShift, in each case of when an upstream `module.xml` is available, provide additional `module.xml` files and file customizations as per instructions in the Liferay User Guide for installing Liferay 6.2 on JBoss AS7 (tentative)
  - **Modify `JAVA_OPTS`** in such a way as that the modified value would actually be utilized when JBoss AS7 is initialized via the `jbossas` cartridge  (presumed possible via OpenShift app "hook" configuration e.g in file `pre_start_jbossas` though an addition to `JAVA_OPTS` in that file may not be picked up by JBoss AS7 itself)
  - **Add a custom Java security framework `server.policy` file**, also referencing the file in the customized `JAVA_OPTS` e.g at location ${OPENSHIFT_JOBSSAS_DIR}/modules/server.policy
  - resulting JAVA_OPTS: `"-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=${OPENSHIFT_JOBSSAS_DIR}/modules/server.policy -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -verbose:class ${JAVA_OPTS}"`

"It can be that simple," one hopes.